# Sort Item to front of a list in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

I am already sorting my list in dart/flutter alphabetically, with

```
a.value['name'].toString().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.value['name'].toString().toLowerCase());
```

However, I would also like to sort one of the items in my list to the front, ignoring the alphabetical sorting. Does anyone know how to do that?

Edit:
Here is my Firebase animated list

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
      query: query,
      sort: (a, b) {
        return a.value['name'].toString().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.value['name'].toString().toLowerCase());
      },
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      defaultChild: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(appTheme.accentColor),
          strokeWidth: 2.0,
        ),
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
        Animation<double> animation, int index) {
          return Item(index);
      },
    )
```

I'm sorting, for example, a list of people's names in this list. But, I want a certain name, "Roger", to always be sorted to the top. How is this possible?

Comment: could you give us more explanation? maybe you can put your sample

Comment: Always return `-1` in `sort: ...` when `a` is that specific item, or `1` if `b` is that item.

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer what do you mean? How is that supposed to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to return -1 & -1 for "Roger" in your sort function:

```
FirebaseAnimatedList(
  query: query,
  sort: (a, b) {
    if (a == "Roger") return -1;
    if (b == "Roger") return 1;
    return a.value['name'].toString().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.value['name'].toString().toLowerCase());
  },
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  defaultChild: Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(appTheme.accentColor),
      strokeWidth: 2.0,
    ),
  ),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
    Animation<double> animation, int index) {
      return Item(index);
  },
)
```